# PHP Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in a script I'm trying to install

Tags: php

I'm totally new at this and have run into a small glitch on a new install and I'm not sure how to fix it.. :(

The error is apparently on this line of code:

```
    $r2->$k = htmlspecialchars($r2->$k);
```

Here is the code above and below:

```
// Display items
while ($r2 = mysql_fetch_object($qr2)) {
    reset($_bnr_list);
    echo "<tr>\n";
    $i = 0;
    while (list($k, $v) = each($_bnr_list)) {
        $i++;
        $r2->$k = htmlspecialchars($r2->$k);
        if ($kq)
            $r2->$k = preg_replace($ks, "<b>\\0</b>", $r2->$k);

        echo "<td class=row2>";
        if ($i == 1)
            echo "Edit: <a href=admin.php?a=bnr/edit&id={$r2->id}&{$_fwk_id}>", ($r2->$k != "" ? $r2->$k : "no name"), "</a>";
        elseif ($i == 2) {
            $mod = "usr";
            list($un) = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT username FROM " . $GLOBALS["_{$mod}_tables"]['list'][0] . " WHERE id={$r2->$k}"));
            echo "<a href=admin.php?a={$mod}/info&id={$r2->$k}&{$_fwk_id}>{$un}</a>";
        } elseif ($i == 5)
            echo round($r2->stat_clicks * 100 / $r2->stat_shows, 3), "%";
        else
            echo ($r2->$k != "" ? $r2->$k : "&nbsp;");
        echo "\n";
    }

    echo "<td class=row2><small>",
    "<!--- <a href=admin.php?a=bnr/del&id={$r2->id}&{$_fwk_id} {$_fwk_js_confirm}>Delete</a> --->",
    "</small>";

    echo "<tr><td colspan=", ($col + 1), ">", $r2->html;
}
```

Comment: Are there any error messages displayed?

Comment: Yes...Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in /home/ --------- on line 243

Comment: This is line 243: $r2->$k = htmlspecialchars($r2->$k);

Answer (score 0):

That error means `$k` is empty and can not be used as property name. `$k` is the key from `$_bnr_list` so you have to trace where does it come from and why does it have empty strings / null values as keys.

Comment: I had this script developed for me about 10 years ago and decided to see if I can get it up and running.. Think I need to hire somebody that knows what they are doing :).. Thanks...